# Javascript - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I am making a very simple drawing web app in p5.js and came across the error.
The error says it is in line 10 but I see no error? Maybe I am doing something wrong with the array.

```
var pixels = [];
var drawing = false;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
function draw() {
    background(0);
    for(var i = pixels.length - 1;i >= 0;i++) {
        pixels[i].show();
    }
    if(drawing) {
        var nP = new Pixel(mouseX, mouseY);
        pixels.push(nP);
    }
}

function mousePressed() {
    drawing = true;
}
function mouseReleased() {
    drawing = false;
}

function Pixel(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.show = function() {
        push();
        noStroke();
        fill(255);
        rect(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
        pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in the code that shows `pixels` being anything other than an empty array. The error indicates that `pixels[i]` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the line-

```
for(var i = pixels.length - 1;i >= 0;i++)
```

For traversing array backwards, you need to decrement the counter, instead of incrementing it. So, the correct loop should be-

```
for(var i = pixels.length - 1;i >= 0;i--)
```